Create two columns with references cited at the bottom of slide inbeamer
URGENT,
Can somebody help me code the following format in latex beamer.

contains heading at the top
two columns for adding the content in the slide.
the details of the references mentioned in the two columns appears on the same slide at the bottom.

I made two columns with headings, but i am unable to do the third one. The references are also appearing in the two columns rather than in a single large column at the bottom.
I tried but not getting the desired results. Please find below my code and outcome.
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
%\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{8}{6}\selectfont}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{orchid}



} 

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=blue!165!black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{theorem}{fg=blue!165!black, bg=white}\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{definition}[numbered]


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}





\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refer.bib}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\addtobeamertemplate{qed symbol}{%
    \color{red}%
}


\newtheorem{exe}{Definition}
\renewcommand*{\theexe}{1}


\AtBeginEnvironment{exe}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=blue!15!}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools builds on and extends amsmath package
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[rectangle]



\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{transparent} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{etex}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}

\newcommand{\semitransp}[2][35]{\color{fg!#1}#2}
\usepackage{hhline} 



\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}






%\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refer.bib}


\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot} Author name 
    %\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\hspace*{3em}   Institute name
   \hfill \hfill \hfill \hspace*{3em} \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%


  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter








\begin{frame}{Heading for the topic}
\begin{columns}

\column{.5\linewidth}
LHS of the slide 
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is the first column. 
\end{itemize}
and the desription continues ...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliqua. \footfullcite{why_bcs_magz}



\column{.5\linewidth}
Right hand side of the slide
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is the second column. 
\end{itemize}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliqua. and the desription terminates here \footfullcite{ambc_survey}. ... 

\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}


refer.bib file
@article{why_bcs_magz,
  title={The art of signal processing in backscatter radio for $\mu$W (or less) Internet of Things: Intelligent signal processing and backscatter radio enabling batteryless connectivity},
  author={Bletsas, Aggelos and Alevizos, Panos N and Vougioukas, Georgios},
  journal={IEEE Signal Processing Magazine},
  volume={35},
  number={5},
  pages={28--40},
  year={2018},
  publisher={IEEE}
}



@article{ambc_survey,
  title={Ambient backscatter communications: A contemporary survey},
  author={Van Huynh, Nguyen and Hoang, Dinh Thai and Lu, Xiao and Niyato, Dusit and Wang, Ping and Kim, Dong In},
  journal={IEEE Communications surveys \& tutorials},
  volume={20},
  number={4},
  pages={2889--2922},
  year={2018},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

Thanks!!



Please provide us with a test file and show what you already tried yourself. This site is not a do-it-for-me service. Sounds as if you are looking for \footfullcite

Welcome to TeX.SX! Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See minimal working example (MWE) for what needs to go into such a document.

Thanks for your suggestions, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and cabohah. I had edited the question and had added my code.

thanks @cabohah for your suggestion I went through MWE  and will make sure I follow it from now onwards..

Your preamble really could do with a clean up. Most of the packages are either not necessary or duplicates.

You can use \footnote[frame]{\fullcite{knuth:ct}} to move the reference to the bottom of the slide:
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Heading for the topic}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
LHS of the slide 
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is the first column. 
\end{itemize}
and the desription continues ...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliqua. \footnote[frame]{\fullcite{angenendt}}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
Right hand side of the slide
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is the second column. 
\end{itemize}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliqua. and the desription terminates here \footnote[frame]{\fullcite{knuth:ct}}.
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you so much, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz its working...
